# why IllegalArgumentException happens in using DownloadManager?

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I used `DownloadManager` in my android project to download a file.

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(soundURL));
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_HIDDEN);
    deleteIfFileExist(filePath);
    request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, SubPath, SndName);
    return manager.enqueue(request);
```

it works fine but i saw in Fabric that some of users reported a crash:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://downloads/my_downloads
   at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:882)
   at android.app.DownloadManager.enqueue(DownloadManager.java:904)
```

I searched about it and found somewhere because their `DownloadManger` is disable. but I saw in android devices that android version is 4 they do not have ability to disable it. can anybody help me why this error happens?

Comment: what is the `soundURL`?

Comment: @VladMatvienko: My download URL. it is a file in my host. I said that works fine for most of users just some of them report a crash

Comment: ok, sorry, the problem is not in source, but in destenation URL

Comment: @VladMatvienko: I handled it if the URL was wrong, the problem is somewhere else

Comment: such a GREAT question ... it is my problem too

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to activate/deactivate Download Manager directly, since it's system application and we don't have access to it.

Only alternative left is to redirect the User to the Info Page of Download Manager Application.

```
try {
     //Open the specific App Info page:
     Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
     intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + "com.android.providers.downloads"));
     startActivity(intent);

} catch ( ActivityNotFoundException e ) {
     e.printStackTrace();

     //Open the generic Apps page:
     Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APPLICATIONS_SETTINGS);
     startActivity(intent);
}
```